# How to delete ngCookie (angular-cookies)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, angular-cookies

I created a cookie called 'stateCookie' when I start my app. As I change state I add variables into that cookie. When I logout, I want this cookie to be completely destroyed, or empty.

[On their docs it's just remove()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies) I've done that but the cookie still exists. ie: `$cookies.remove('stateCookie');`

After logout and login: 
`>>> refreshCookie {"ticker":"SPY","term_id_1":5112166,"term_id_2":30111615,"term_id_3":13064871}`

[image]

---

```
this.logout = () => AuthFactory.webservice_logout().then((res) => {
    // $cookies.remove('stateCookie');
    angular.forEach($cookies, function(value, key) {
        $cookies.remove(key);
    });

    // console.log('$cookies', $cookies);

    // $cookies.map((value, key) => {
    //  $cookies.remove(key);
    // });

    const refreshCookie = $cookies.get('stateCookie');
    console.log('!!!refreshCookie', refreshCookie);
    $state.go('login', {}).then(() => {
        $state.reload();
    });
});
```

### Hack fix

I'm able to clear the cookie by calling window.reload after going back to the `login` state.

`$state.go('login', {}).then(() => window.location.reload(true));`

Comment: Tried that, the cookie still exists :( also after login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
this.logout = () => AuthFactory.webservice_logout().then((res) => {
    // $cookies.remove('stateCookie');
    var cookies = $cookies.getAll();
    console.log(cookies);
    angular.forEach(cookies, function(value, key) {
        $cookies.remove(key);
    });

    // console.log('$cookies', $cookies);

    // $cookies.map((value, key) => {
    //  $cookies.remove(key);
    // });

    const refreshCookie = $cookies.get('stateCookie');
    console.log('!!!refreshCookie', refreshCookie);
    $state.go('login', {}).then(() => {
        $state.reload();
    });
});
```

Comment: Ok well this works, but I had to still use `window.location.reload(true)` instead of `$state.reload()`